# Use Picasso to load image into programmatically added ImageView [NOT WORKING]

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, picasso

I'm trying to add a ImageView to a RelativeLayout and then use Picasso to load an image into this ImageView. However, this isn't working. The URL to the image is valid. I'm not sure if the issue is with Picasso or if the ImageView isn't being added.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed_view);

ImageView methodImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

RelativeLayout detailsLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.details_layout);
TextView transportationText = (TextView) detailsLayout.findViewById(R.id.transportationText);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(5, 5);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, transportationText.getId());
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, transportationText.getId());
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, transportationText.getId());

methodImage.setLayoutParams(params);

detailsLayout.addView(methodImage);

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(img_url).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).fit().centerCrop().into(methodImage);
```

**activity_detailed_view.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/details_layout">>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="275dp"
    android:id="@+id/image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/name2"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/date2"
        android:layout_below="@id/name2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/creator_name2"
        android:layout_below="@id/date2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@id/venues"
        android:layout_below="@+id/creator_name2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/transportationText"
        android:layout_below="@id/venues"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_below="@id/transportationText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Layout]

Comment: "or if the ImageView isn't being added" -- add a `placeholder()` to your Picasso setup, to load an image in there while the real image is being downloaded, to help perhaps debug this problem. It's also possible that because the `ImageView` has not been laid out yet, Picasso is coming up with the wrong size information (e.g., 0 by 0). You might try delaying your Picasso work a bit. I also recommend using `this` rather than `getApplicationContext()` for GUI work. Also, why are you adding this `ImageView` dynamically in the first place, since you just loaded the layout?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these debugging tips. I'm adding the image dynamically because the number of images that I need to load is dynamic. This code is actually in a loop so that I can load as many images as I need. @CommonsWare

Comment: Ah, OK, I was just going by the code snippet from the question. Though, usually, for "as many images as I need", the recommended approach is to use `RecyclerView` or some flavor of `AdapterView`, rather than dynamically adding `ImageView` widgets yourself.

Comment: Hmmmmmmm... that does sound a bit more efficient, though, the number I'd need to load is probably 2 or 3. Do you think I'd experience any significant performance differences by using RecyclerView or AdapterView method over loading the ImageView widgets myself? @CommonsWare

Comment: "the number I'd need to load is probably 2 or 3" -- that's small enough that the benefit of an adapter-based view probably isn't worth it. If, however, you think there's a decent chance that the number will increase in the future, it may be worthwhile.

Comment: I've added the placeholder, per the above code change and still nothing is displayed. How would you suggest that I delay the Picasso work? @CommonsWare

Comment: First, you might double-check with Hierarchy Viewer or **`uiautomatorviewer`** to ensure that your `ImageView` is showing up and is merely empty for some reason. The crude way of delaying this work would be to `post()` a `Runnable` on `methodImage` or some other `View`, where the Picasso work is done in `run()`. The better approach is to use `ViewTreeObserver` to register a listener for layout changes, but this is a bit more complex.

Comment: Can you show as an image of the layout that you want to achieve ,just pasted your layout file and it is all messed up

Comment: Hierarchy Viewer is indicating that my ImageView is indeed showing up. @CommonsWare . I'll look into delaying the Picasso work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** Just change this line

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Second to resize ImageView Use `Picasso` function `resize(int,int)`

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
     .load(img_url)
     .resize(5,5)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .fit().centerCrop().into(methodImage);
```

Don't use `android:layout_below="@+id/something"` use this way `android:layout_below="@id/something"` .We use @+id only for the first time when we declare id , when we are referencing ids we use @id/something

Comment: I've updated my code based on your suggestion, however, this did not solve the issue. I've updated the question with my current layout. What I want to do is to dynamically add images next to the "Transportation: " TextView. I have images such as boat.png, airplane.png, etc...

Comment: Just updated the code , If still there is problem let me know

Comment: Wow... that's actually the exact line that I had when I posted the question and somewhere along debugging, I changed it. So yes, it seems like your original solution was correct. Working now, thanks... But how do I specify the length and width of the newly created ImageView to both be 5dp?

Comment: You can use Picasso.(getApplicationCOntext()).resize(5,5).....  to resize the image